# Match any value from list of strings

Tags: c#, pact, consumer, contract, pact-net

I new pact testing, I have a pact consumer test in which a property can have any value from a defined set of string:

```
this.pact
        .ExpectsToReceive("an event indicating that an order has been created")
        .WithJsonContent(new
            {
               PayloadType = Match.MinType(new List<string> { "apple", "orange" }, 1),
           })
```

Not sure how to match `PayloadType` to have one value either "apple" or "orange". Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Match.Regex` to achieve matching strings:

```
this.pact
        .ExpectsToReceive("an event indicating that an order has been created")
        .WithJsonContent(new
            {
               PayloadType = Match.Regex("apple", ("apple|orange")),
           })
```